# Remove simultaneity from list of tuples from list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I'm trying to do this in a fast and efficient way

input:

```
a = [(1,0),(2,3),(0,1),(4,6),(3,2)]
```

do something :
I know that (1,0) is not equal to (0,1) but in my application I just need one of them

and since I have more than 6194913 elements it takes a very long time to run the app

output:

```
a = [(1,0),(2,3),(4,6)]
```

Comment: Should the the output keep the first encounter? i.e. `(1,0)` and not `(0,1)`?

Answer (score 1):

One possible way:

```
a = [(1,0),(2,3),(0,1),(4,6),(3,2)]
a = list(set([tuple(sorted(item)) for item in a]))
print(a) #[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 6)]
```

1. Sort every tuple in `a` <sup>(to turn `(g, f)` into `(f, g)` but keep `(f, g)` <sup>f < g</sup>)</sup>
2. Cast to a `set` to remove duplicates
3. Cast back to `list` from `set`

The `tuple` cast is to ensure hashability, since `sorted` converts to a `list` and `list`s are unhashable.

```
>>> sorted((1, 0)) #converts to list
[0, 1]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove duplicates, we can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) here.

However, we need to find a way to determine if tuples are equal to their reversed form, such as `(1, 0)` is equal to `(0, 1)`. If we test this, we realise that they are *not* equal by themselves:

```
>>> (1, 0) == (0, 1)
False
```

As shown in the other answer by [@A.J. Uppal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62622573/remove-simultaneity-from-list-of-tuples-from-list-of-tuples/62622614#62622614), we can *sort* the tuple before doing the equality check:

```
>>> tuple(sorted((1, 0))) == tuple(sorted((0, 1)))
True
```

Which now shows that tuples are *equal* according to our criteria.

Furthermore, sets require *hashable*(immutable) types, so tuples can be used here. Mutable types are *not* hashable, which cannot be used with `set`.

Another hashable type we can use here is [`frozenset`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset):

```
>>> frozenset((1, 0)) == frozenset((0, 1))
True
```

Which can used to remove *any* of the duplicates:

```
>>> a = [(1,0),(2,3),(0,1),(4,6),(3,2)]
>>> set(frozenset(t) for t in a)
{frozenset({0, 1}), frozenset({4, 6}), frozenset({2, 3})}
>>> [tuple(s) for s in set(frozenset(t) for t in a)]
[(0, 1), (4, 6), (2, 3)]
```

However, the above does not maintain order. If we want to maintain order, we can use a *set* to keep track of duplicates:

```
a = [(1,0),(2,3),(0,1),(4,6),(3,2)]

seen = set()
result = []

for tup in a:
    fs = frozenset(tup)
    if fs not in seen:
        result.append(tup)
        seen.add(fs)

print(result)
```

Which gives this *ordered* output:

```
[(1, 0), (2, 3), (4, 6)]
```

**Note:** Using `frozenset` is `O(n)`, which is more efficient than `O(nlogn)`sorting. For larger lists, I recommend using `frozenset`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sample = [(1, 0), (2, 3), (0, 1), (4, 6), (3, 2)]
result = set()

for first, second in sample:
    if (first, second) not in result and (second, first) not in result:
        result.add((first, second))

result = list(result)
print(result)
```

### Output:

```
[(1, 0), (2, 3), (4, 6)]
```